# setting log-uniform priors in Stan

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, prior, uniform-distribution, logarithm, stan

I have been using [Stan](http://mc-stan.org/) for a couple months now and I want to adopt a log-uniform prior on some parameter array `real theta[N]`.  I want to do something like a sampling statement, i.e. ...

`theta ~ log_uniform(0.001,10.);`

but based on the [user manual](http://mc-stan.org/documentation/) (Chapter 5 onwards), Stan doesn't seem to support a log-uniform distribution in this manner. I thought about instead setting a uniform prior on log_theta, i.e. ...

`log_theta ~ uniform(-3.,1.);`

then somehow doing `theta <- 10^log_theta` but I'm still a novice regarding the Stan syntax. Is there an (even more) elegant workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you can achieve a log-uniform prior by declaring `log_theta` in the parameters block with `lower=-3` and `upper=1` like

`parameters {
  real<lower=-3,upper=1> log_theta;
  ...`

and then do in the transformed parameters block or model block

`real theta;
theta <- 10 ^ log_theta;`

It is never necessary in Stan to explicitly use the uniform density because if you simply omit it, then there is nothing to make the prior non-uniform over the support for the parameter as declared in the parameters block.

All that said, it is usually a bad idea from a Bayesian perspective to impose lower and / or upper bounds that are not logically necessary for the data-generating process. If your bounds are too tight, then no matter how much data you have, you can never concentrate the posterior distribution on the true parameter value. Also, in Stan it is computationally necessary that there be zero *posterior* density at the endpoints of the support. You can have non-zero *prior* density at the endpoints of the support but are relying on the data to bound the posterior density away from the endpoints.